# My mathematical function that adds a sum to the total sum doesn't work. I get error message "sum not defined"

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a react app that lets a user enter an item, number of items and the price, then the user inputs several items that get listed and the total amount should be incremented every time a new item is entered. My function that adds a total sum to the sum (items price) doesn't seem to work. I have a sum as a property and totalSum as a property. How do i setSate(totalSum) with the "this.state.sum"?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';


export default class Kvitton extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            produkter: [], 
            produkt: '',
            antal:"",
            pris: "",
            sum:"",
            totalSum:""
            
        
        }
    this.eFormChange = this.eFormChange.bind(this);
    //this.eSumma = this.eSumma.bind(this);
    this.eSubmit  = this.eSubmit.bind(this);       
    console.log('constructor'); 
}

render() {
    console.log('Render'); 
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Kvitto</h3>
           
            <form onSubmit={this.eSubmit} >
                <p>
                    <label htmlFor="produkt">Produkt: </label>
                    <input id="produkt" onChange={this.eFormChange} value={this.state.produkt} />

                </p>
                <p>
                    <label htmlFor="antal">Antal: </label>
                    <input id="antal" onChange={this.eFormChange} value={this.state.antal} />

                </p>
                <p>
                    <label htmlFor="pris">Pris: </label>
                    <input id="pris" name="pris" onChange={this.eFormChange} value={this.state.pris} />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Submit </button>
                </p>
                 <p> <ProduktLista produktItems={this.state.produkter} /> </p>
                <p>
                      <label htmlFor="produkt"> </label> 
                      <span> Summa: {this.doTotalSum(this.state.summa, this.state.totalSumman)} </span>
                </p>

                
                
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

eFormChange (e) {
    var inputObj = {};
    inputObj[e.target.id] = e.target.value;                 
    this.setState( inputObj );
    console.log("-----------"+ inputObj);
}

eSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('submit');
    if (this.state.produkt.length === 0 ) {
        return alert("You have not given a product");
    }
    if (this.state.antal.length === 0 || !Number(this.state.antal))  {
        return alert("Antal has to be a number");
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.pris.length === 0 || !Number(this.state.antal)) {
        return alert("Price has to be a number");
    }
    const newProduct = { 
        produkt: this.state.produkt,
        antal: this.state.antal, 
        pris: this.state.pris,
        sum: (this.state.antal) *  (this.state.pris),
        totalSum: + {sum}

    };
  
    this.setState(state => ({
      produkter: state.produkter.concat(newProduct),
      produkt: '',
      antal:'',
      pris: '',
      sum:'',
      totalSum:''
    }));
} 
   
    }
  
    const ProduktLista = ({ produktItems }) => {
        return (
          <ul>
            {produktItems.map(({ antal, pris, produkt, sum, totalSum }) => (
                <li key={produkt}>
                    {produkt + ' - ' + antal + ' - ' + pris + '   ' }
                    summan: {antal*pris});
                </li>
             ))} 
          </ul>
        );
      }
   
    function doTotalSum(summa, totalSumman) {
      const result = summa + totalSumman;
       return result;
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited my answer of your changed whole code. Please let me know if it is what you need.

```js
import React from 'react';

const ProduktLista = ({produktItems}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {produktItems.map(({antal, pris, produkt, sum, totalSum}) => (
        <li key={produkt}>
          {produkt + ' - ' + antal + ' - ' + pris + '   '}
          summan: {sum});
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default class Kvitton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      produkter: [],
      produkt: '',
      antal: '',
      pris: '',
      sum: 0,
      totalSum: 0,
    };
    this.eFormChange = this.eFormChange.bind(this);
    //this.eSumma = this.eSumma.bind(this);
    this.eSubmit = this.eSubmit.bind(this);
    console.log('constructor');
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Render');
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Kvitto</h3>

        <form onSubmit={this.eSubmit}>
          <p>
            <label htmlFor="produkt">Produkt: </label>
            <input
              id="produkt"
              onChange={this.eFormChange}
              value={this.state.produkt}
            />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label htmlFor="antal">Antal: </label>
            <input
              id="antal"
              onChange={this.eFormChange}
              value={this.state.antal}
            />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label htmlFor="pris">Pris: </label>
            <input
              id="pris"
              name="pris"
              onChange={this.eFormChange}
              value={this.state.pris}
            />
          </p>
          <p>
            <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Submit </button>
          </p>
          <p>
            {' '}
            <ProduktLista produktItems={this.state.produkter} />{' '}
          </p>
          <p>
            <label htmlFor="produkt"> </label>
            <span> Summa: {this.state.totalSum} </span>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  eFormChange(e) {
    var inputObj = {};
    inputObj[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(inputObj);
    console.log('-----------' + inputObj);
  }

  eSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('submit');
    if (this.state.produkt.length === 0) {
      return alert('You have not given a product');
    }
    if (this.state.antal.length === 0 || !Number(this.state.antal)) {
      return alert('Antal has to be a number');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.pris.length === 0 || !Number(this.state.antal)) {
      return alert('Price has to be a number');
    }

    const sum = this.state.antal * this.state.pris;
    const newProduct = {
      produkt: this.state.produkt,
      antal: this.state.antal,
      pris: this.state.pris,
      sum,
      totalSum: this.state.totalSum + sum,
    };

    this.setState({
      produkter: this.state.produkter.concat(newProduct),
      produkt: '',
      antal: '',
      pris: '',
      sum,
      totalSum: this.state.totalSum + sum,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I'm still not getting it to add to the totalSum. Not not whether my function is faulty.

Comment: `produkter` array includes `sum` and `totalSum`, also this.state has `sum` and `totalSum`. Are they used for different purpose?

Comment: they are the same. Sum is simply the cost of the item entered. Them totalSum is the total for all items entered.

Comment: not sure if i understand with the edited answer. Do you mean that i change to the red marked text?

Comment: You can simply copy all and try to run it on your side. Actually, I tried to run your code on my side and changed the current code.

Comment: i've tried to change and run again, but totalSum isn't adding up. Chech my result below:



    mango - 2st - 12 summan: 24);
    juice - 2st - 15 summan: 30);

Summa: ?????   (should have been 24+30=54)

Comment: please try to run this codesandbox and let me know if it is correct or not - https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-hill-58tkk

Comment: Thank you abundantly. It worked as i wanted. Thanks again for your help.